# VIM vimscript: autocmd to set foldcolumn to value of foldlevel

Tags: vim, editor, vim-plugin, fold, neovim

I aim to auto set `foldcolumn` to deepest [foldlevel](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#foldlevel()).

In **.vimrc** I tried:

```
autocmd FileType html :set foldmethod=syntax
autocmd FileType html :let &foldcolumn=&foldlevel
```

But shows error:

> Error detected while processing FileType Autocommands for "html":
>   E521: Number required after =: foldcolumn=&foldlevel

A workaround would be:

1st: set in .vimrc just:

```
autocmd FileType html :set foldmethod=syntax
```

and execute next map opening the buffer:

```
nnoremap <leader>cf  :let &foldcolumn=&foldlevel<cr>:set foldcolumn?<cr>
```

Or increase 1 by 1

```
nnoremap <leader>cf  :let &foldcolumn = &foldcolumn + 1<cr>:set foldcolumn?<cr>
```

But it could be awesome if it were automatic. How can I solve the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `set foldcolumn to deepest foldlevel.` What?! It doesn't make sense, as foldcolumn is a width value.

Comment: hi @Matt ! Thanks for answering. I might not explained myself. E.g. if we fold by indent, and a buffer has maximum 3 tabs in a row, then my request is to auto set foldcolumn to 3 there. Analogous for other indents methods (except manual). The way I think the solution could be is like the following for textwidth: 1st, open an unwrapped file, 2nd, check every line for the number of chars in each line, 3rd, set the maximum to textwidth. But I do not have the skills to implement so far.